# Dropdown Error : Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\EnfantsController::create(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected

Tags: php, laravel-5, dropdown

So, I have an assistant and enfant tables. I made a dropdown list to affect an assistant from DB while the registration of an enfant. I don't know whats wrong I keep getting this error "Type error: Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\EnfantsController::create(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected". So this is my Enfants Controller :

```
public function create($nom)
{
    $assistants =Assistant::all();
    return view('enfants.create' ,['ass'=>$assistants, 'nom'=>$nom]);


}
```

And this is my create.blade.php :

```
 <select class="form-control select2" id="ass_name" name="ass_name" required>
                        @foreach($ass as $value)
                            <option value="{{ $value->nom }}">{{ $value->nom }}</option>
                        @endforeach
 </select>
```

And, in the option values , I want to have the name of the assistant and then get the id of the selected name and add it to the foreign key "assistant_id" in my enfant table. I hope you get what i want to do, i'm new to Laravel. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your EnfantsController@create method. As you can see its expecting an argument which is a query param that you mention in your routes file. You need to pass value for $nom parameter when you make call to the create method.